# CodeIgniter: show a view by typing its url

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, controller

A newbie here: sorry if the question is too simple, been looking in tutorials but I don't seem to look properly.

I have the

```
$route['default_controller'] = "mainpage";
```

in routes.php working properly, and now I just want to view one of the php pages in views folder by typing its url:

http://myserver/folder/thepageIwantToSee

I get a 404 Not Found error. Do I have to use a controller? I just want to see it first before any linking, is there a way to do it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class yourcontroller extends CI_Controller {

     function pageiwanttosee()
     {
         code
         code

         $this->load->view('the_view_page', $data);
     }

 }
```

Comment: that will actually evaluate it, I think that's not what the OP wants.

Comment: @yi_H how so? He clearly needed an example of how to show a page other than the default one that's loaded by CI.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write a controller that displays the view specified.

http://myserver/showfile/folder/thepageIwantToSee , where showfile is your controller.

Don't forget to set some security check or disable this on production site.